# change name in hyperref

Tags: equations, hyperref, autoref

I am trying to change the name of equation in hyperref. For this I use the command:

```
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\equationeautorefname{\itshape Gleichung}}
```

If I use \autoref, for section, subsection and subsubsection works this. But unfortunately not for equations.
Here is my code:

```
%Dokumentklasse
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, pointlessnumbers,  twoside, numbers=noenddot, captions=nooneline]{scrreprt}

%===Seitenränder===%
\usepackage[left = 2.5cm, right = 2.5cm, top = 3cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}

%===Abstand zu Kapitelüberschriften==%
\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{18pt}}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\vspace*{3pt}}

%===Zeilenabstand===%
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%============= Packages =============%

% Dokumentinformationen
\usepackage[
    pdftitle={blablabla},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfauthor={},
    pdfkeywords={}, 
    hidelinks
]{hyperref}

%===Standard Packages===%
%STANDARD-Pakete
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[german]{varioref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{linktoc=all, colorlinks=true, bookmarks=true, pdftitle={Bachelorarbeit-TITEL}}

%===Tabellen und Abbildungsbeschriftung===%
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{\itshape Bild}}
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\figureautorefname{\itshape Bild}} 

\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\tablename}{\itshape Tabelle}}
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\tableautorefname{\itshape Tabelle}}

\addto\extrasngerman{\def\subsectionautorefname{Unterkapitel}}
  \addto\extrasngerman{\def\sectionautorefname{Kapitel}}
   \addto\extrasngerman{\def\subsubsectionautorefname{Abschnitt}}

   \addto\extrasngerman{\def\equationeautorefname{\itshape Gleichung}}

%Fortlaufende Nummerierung
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

% ============= Dokumentbeginn =============

\begin{document}
```

Someone know the Problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo: `\equationeautorefname` instead of `\equationatorefname`.

On the other hand, your preamble needs some work: you're loading `hyperref` too early and do some small mistakes.

```
%Dokumentklasse
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, pointlessnumbers,  twoside, numbers=noenddot, captions=nooneline]{scrreprt}

%===Seitenränder===%
\usepackage[left = 2.5cm, right = 2.5cm, top = 3cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}

%===Abstand zu Kapitelüberschriften==%
\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace*{18pt}}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\vspace*{3pt}}

%===Zeilenabstand===%
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%============= Packages =============%

%===Standard Packages===%
%STANDARD-Pakete
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[german]{varioref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{caption}

% Dokumentinformationen
\usepackage[
    pdftitle={blablabla},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfauthor={},
    pdfkeywords={}, 
    hidelinks
]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{linktoc=all, colorlinks=true, bookmarks=true, pdftitle={Bachelorarbeit-TITEL}}

%===Tabellen und Abbildungsbeschriftung===%
\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{\textit{Bild}}%
  \renewcommand{\tablename}{\textit{Tabelle}}%
}
\addto\extrasngerman{%
  \def\figureautorefname{\textit{Bild}} %
  \def\tableautorefname{\textit{Tabelle}}%
  \def\subsectionautorefname{Unterkapitel}%
  \def\sectionautorefname{Kapitel}%
  \def\subsubsectionautorefname{Abschnitt}%
  \def\equationautorefname{\textit{Gleichung}}%
}

%Fortlaufende Nummerierung
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

% ============= Dokumentbeginn =============

\begin{document}

\section{Titel}\label{test-a}
\subsection{Titel}\label{test-b}
Aaa bbb
\begin{equation}\label{test-c}
x
\end{equation}

\autoref{test-a}\par
\autoref{test-b}\par
\autoref{test-c} ccc ddd

\end{document}
```

Are you sure you need all those package? In particular, are you sure about `subfig` instead of the more powerful `subcaption`?

[image]